# Nokogiri Scraping Misses HTML

Tags: ruby, web-scraping, nokogiri

Nokogiri isn't grabbing anything beneath the `iframe` tag.

`doc.search("iframe")` returns only the `iframe` tag.  `doc.search("body.content-frame")` returns empty.  `doc.errors` returns empty also.  Why isn't Nokogiri registering the HTML beneath the iframe? How can I grab it?

```
<html lang="en" xml:lang="en" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

    <head></head>
    <body onunload="clearMyTimeInterval()">
       <iframe id="content-frame" frameborder="0" src="/sportsbook/betting-lines/baseball/2014-08-21/?range=day" onload="javascript:checkLoadedFrame(this);" style="background-color: rgb(34, 34, 34); height: 1875px;" name="content-frame" scrolling="no" border="0">
           #document
           <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
           <html lang="en" xml:lang="en" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
            <head></head>
            <body class="content-frame">
             #ETC.......
```

Comment: Let me know if you want me to post more HTML.  I tried to cut the HTML to what was necessary.

Comment: Turn off JavaScript in your browser, reload the page, then look at both the page in the browser's pane and in the source. The source is what Nokogiri would receive and work with.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is code that handles it:

```
page = Mechanize.new.get "http://page_u_need"
page.iframe_with(id: 'beatles').content
```

Comment: When answering it's much more useful to explain how the code works and why it should be the selected answer. We're trying to educate, not just merely supply code.

Answer (score 3):

That's because the contents of the `iframe` are not part of the page. In fact, they are in a completely different location (note the `src` attribute of the `iframe`). You'll have to fetch that content separately, which is how a browser would do it.