# Web page scraped with Nokogiri returns no data

Tags: ruby, web-scraping, nokogiri, frames

I am trying to scrape a project list from the British government's [UK Oil Portal](https://itportal.decc.gov.uk/pathfinder/currentprojectsindex.html), but my code returns no data.  Instead, I want to make an array of project titles.

```rb
class Entry
  def initialize(title)
    @title = title
  end
  attr_reader :title
end

def index
  @projects=Project.all
  require 'open-uri'
  require 'nokogiri'
  doc = Nokogiri::HTML(open("https://itportal.decc.gov.uk/pathfinder/currentprojectsindex.html"))

  entries = doc.css('.operator-container')
  @entries = []
  entries.each do |row|
    title = row.css('.setoutForm').text
    @entries << Entry.new(title)
  end
end
```

Comment: entries = doc.css('.operator-container') in this section you need to specify the content which you want from html tag like suppose i have div which has class container then it should be like doc.css('div container')

Comment: @fred if you solved this yourself, please consider posting your own answer

Comment: see also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25436818/nokogiri-scraping-misses-html

Comment: Please read "[mcve]". When asking we need to see the minimum HTML necessary to demonstrate the problem _in the question itself_, along with the minimum code that uses that data that demonstrates the problem. Asking us to go to off-site links and parse through it wastes our time that could be used to help others, so help us help you.

Comment: Why did you override my edit? As @theTinMan said, it is important that the example should be complete, so please include samples of the HTML source that you scraped.

Comment: It's improper to add or modify code and, by extension, the data necessary to make the question sensible. At the same time, it's a requirement that we have that necessary data when asking about a problem involving the code. "[mcve]". Without that data the question is off-topic, so simply downvote it and vote to close.

Comment: @theTinMan https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/314190/when-to-add-code-to-a-users-question

Comment: @fred pls add the missing code to your question

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The link you posted contains no data.  The page you see is a frameset, with each frame created by its own URL. You want to parse the left frame, so you should edit your code to open the  URL of the left frame:

```
  doc = Nokogiri::HTML(open('https://itportal.decc.gov.uk/eng/fox/path/PATH_REPORTS/current-projects-index'))
```

The individual projects are on separate pages, and you need to open each one. For example the first one is:

```
project_file = open(entries.first.css('a').attribute('href').value)       
project_doc = Nokogiri::HTML(project_file)
```

The "setoutForm" class scrapes lots of text.  For example:

```
> project_doc.css('.setoutForm').text
=> "\n            \n              Field Type\n              Location\n              Water De
pth (m)\n              First Production\n              Contact\n            \n            \n
              Oil\n              2/15\n              155m\n              Q3/2018\n          
    \n                John Gill\n                Business Development Manager\n             
   jgill@alphapetroleum.com\n                01483 307204\n              \n            \n   
       \n            \n              Project Summary\n            \n            \n          
    \n                The Cheviot discovery is located in blocks 2/10a, 2/15a and 3/11b. \n 
               \n                Reserves are approximately 46mmbbls oil.\n                \
n                A Field Development Plan has been submitted and technically approved. The c
oncept is for a leased FPSA with 18+ subsea wells. Oil export will be via tanker offloading.
\n                \n              \n            \n          "
```

However the title is not in that text. If you want the title, scrape this part of the page:

```
<div class="field-header" foxid="eu1KcH_d4qniAjiN">Cheviot</div>
```

Which you could do with this CSS selector:

```
> project_doc.css('.operator-container .field-header').text
=> "Cheviot"
```

Write this code step by step.  It is hard to find out where your code goes wrong, unless you single-step it. For example, I used Nokogiri's [command line tool](https://robm.me.uk/ruby/2014/01/06/nokogiri-command-line.html) to open an interactive Ruby shell, with

```
nokogiri https://itportal.decc.gov.uk/eng/fox/path/PATH_REPORTS/current-projects-index
```

Comment: @fred If my answer helped, and is the quality you expect here, please consider up-voting and accepting it.

Comment: Don't use `css` and `text` unless you understand what is going to happen. Instead, use one of the `at` variants with `text` or `map(&:text)` on `search`, `css`, or `xpath`. See https://stackoverflow.com/q/43594656/128421.